# R - Add new variable of (summary) to data frame satisfying multiple conditions

Tags: r, function, apply

I have long data frame and here's sample.

```
df <- data.frame(numid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
                ,id=c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C')
                ,t1=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2)
                ,t2=c(1,3,2,4,4,6,5))
```

here it is.

```
numid   id  t1  t2
    1   A   1   1
    2   A   2   3
    3   A   3   2
    4   B   1   4
    5   B   2   4
    6   C   1   6
    7   C   2   5
```

here's problem, Now I want to add new variable(t3).
t3 is max(t2) of rows satisfying two conditions
1. within same ID group
2. t1 is smaller than its own t1

I made loop to solve this and this is working but too slow.

```
for(i in 1:7){
  cid <- df[i,"id"]
  ct1 <- df[i,"t1"]
  tmp <- df[df$id==cid & df$t1 < ct1,]
  df[i,"t3"] <- max(tmp$t2)
}
```

the result is

```
  numid id  t1  t2  t3
    1   A   1   1   -Inf
    2   A   2   3   1
    3   A   3   2   3
    4   B   1   4   -Inf
    5   B   2   4   4
    6   C   1   6   -Inf
    7   C   2   5   6
```

Somebody help me to make this code much faster

Comment: What do you mean by "t1 is smaller than its own t1"? Also, please try to format your output properly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[,t3:= c(-Inf,Reduce(max,t2,accumulate = T)[-.N]),by=id]
```

Seems like your t1 is already in a ascending order in each id group. If not, you need to sort your data frame or data table first.

**A more efficient version according to David Arenburg:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,t3:=shift(cummax(t2),fill=-Inf),by=id]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's fast enough.

Comment: Awesome！Thanks！@DavidArenburg

Comment: I'll add these in.